# Alignment of pictures in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm having some trouble with drawing a couple of pictures in TikZ. It puts a different alignment on two adjacent pictures, as follows:

[image]

Also, how can I get the "and" to be centered vertically?

My apologies if this is a repeat question. It must have shown up before, but I didn't see it. Here is the code. Any other comments and suggestions are appreciated, since I'm just learning TikZ.

**Edit:** I gather that the different alignment is because of the label that's included on the bottom of the right one. But I'm still wondering how to get the "and" centered vertically.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate
(a0) at (0,0);
\coordinate
(a1) at (5,5);
\coordinate[label=left:$g$] (a2) at (2.5,3.5);
\fill (a2) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=above:$X$] (a3) at (2.5,5);
\coordinate[label=left:$f$] (a4) at (2.5,2.25);
\fill (a4) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=above:$\varepsilon$] (a5) at (3.5,1.5);
\fill (a5) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=below:$Y$] (a6) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate
(a8) at (4.35,2.5);
\coordinate[label=above:$L$] (a9) at (4.5,5);
\draw (a0) rectangle (a1);
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(a4) (a5) (a8) (a9)};
\draw (a3) -- (a2) -- (a4) -- (a6);
\coordinate[label=$\mathbf{1}$] (1) at (1,3);
\coordinate[label=$\mathscr{D}$] (D) at (3.4,3.4);
 \coordinate[label=$\mathscr{C}$] (C) at (3.78,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
$\qquad$and$\qquad$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,3);
\draw (0,3.5) rectangle (5,5);
\draw (2.5, 5) -- (2.5, 3.5);
\draw (4, 5) -- (4, 3.5);
\coordinate[label=above:$X$] (X) at (2.5, 5);
\coordinate[label=above:$L$] (X) at (4, 5);
\draw (2.5, 3) -- (2.5, 1.8) -- (1,0);
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(2.5, 1.8) (3.4, 1) (4, 1.8) (4, 3)};
 \coordinate[label=below:$\varepsilon$] (epsilon) at (3.4, 1);
\fill (epsilon) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=left:$g$] (g) at (2.5, 4);
  \fill (g) circle (2pt);
  \coordinate[label=left:$f$] (f) at (2.5, 1.8);
  \fill (f) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not on my computer right now, but try adding a `%` after the first `\end{tikzpicture}`. Also, why the dollar signs around `\qquad`?

Comment: Hmmm that didn't help. However, I think I figured out one part of it: the misalignment is due to a label that's in one, but not the other. But I still don't know how to get the "and" to align.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is use `baseline=25mm` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=25mm]
\coordinate                 (a0) at (0,0);
\coordinate                 (a1) at (5,5);
\coordinate[label=left:$g$] (a2) at (2.5,3.5);
\fill (a2) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=above:$X$](a3) at (2.5,5);
\coordinate[label=left:$f$] (a4) at (2.5,2.25);
\fill (a4) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=above:$\varepsilon$] (a5) at (3.5,1.5);
\fill (a5) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=below:$Y$](a6) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate                 (a8) at (4.35,2.5);
\coordinate[label=above:$L$](a9) at (4.5,5);
\draw (a0) rectangle (a1);
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(a4) (a5) (a8) (a9)};
\draw (a3) -- (a2) -- (a4) -- (a6);
\coordinate[label=$\mathbf{1}$]     (1) at (1,3);
\coordinate[label=$\mathscr{D}$]    (D) at (3.4,3.4);
 \coordinate[label=$\mathscr{C}$]   (C) at (3.78,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfil and\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=25mm]
    \draw (0,0)   rectangle (5,3);
    \draw (0,3.5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw (2.5, 5) -- (2.5, 3.5);
    \draw (4, 5)   -- (4, 3.5);
\coordinate[label=above:$X$] (X) at (2.5,5);
\coordinate[label=above:$L$] (L) at (4.0,5);  
    \draw (2.5, 3) -- (2.5, 1.8) -- (1,0);
    \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(2.5, 1.8) (3.4, 1) (4, 1.8) (4, 3)};
\coordinate[label=below:$\varepsilon$] (epsilon) at (3.4, 1);
    \fill (epsilon) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=left:$g$] (g) at (2.5, 4);
  \fill (g) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=left:$f$] (f) at (2.5, 1.8);
  \fill (f) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

In code I also fix some glitches as mentioned Alenanno in his comment as correct duplication of coordinate names. With this correction I got:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Yeah, that's great!